# Найти слово и сделать из него имя файла

Tags: vba, ms-word, rtf

Помогите, пожалуйста, чтобы он искал слово "ИД" в тексте и копировал через пробел набор цифр и присваивал названию файла эти цифры. Также не могу понять почему буква Б так странно отображается (не полностью) под строкой г.. Уфа

Скрин файла, необходимая строка выглядит вот так:
Госпошлина за рассмотрение дела в суде в отношении Иванова Ивана Ивановича (кредитный договор S_LN_2300_54352), (ИД 654234), НДС нет.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitIntoPages()
Dim docMultiple As Document
Dim docSingle As Document
Dim rngPage As Range
Dim iCurrentPage As Integer
Dim iPageCount As Integer
Dim strNewFileName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Делает код работать быстрее и уменьшает мерцание экрана немного.
Set docMultiple = ActiveDocument 'Работа с активным документом(тот, который в настоящее время содержит выделение)
Set rngPage = docMultiple.Range 'Создать экземпляр объекта range
iCurrentPage = 1
'Получить количество страниц документа
iPageCount = docMultiple.Content.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
Do Until iCurrentPage > iPageCount
If iCurrentPage = iPageCount Then
rngPage.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End 'Последняя страница (следующей страницы не будет)
Else
'Найдите начало следующей страницы
'Необходимо использовать объект выбора. Range. Метод goto не будет работать на странице
Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, iCurrentPage + 1
'Установите конец диапазона в точку между страницами
rngPage.End = Selection.Start
End If
rngPage.Copy 'Копировать страницу в буфер обмена Windows
Set docSingle = Documents.Add 'Создание нового документа
docSingle.Range.Paste 'Вставьте содержимое буфера обмена в новый документ
'Удалите любой разрыв страницы вручную, чтобы предотвратить второй пробел
docSingle.Range.Find.Execute Findtext:="^m", ReplaceWith:=""
'Создайте новое последовательно пронумерованное имя файла на основе исходного многостраничного имени файла и пути к нему
strNewFileName = Replace(docMultiple.FullName, ".rtf", "_" & Right$("000" & iCurrentPage, 4) & ".rtf")
docSingle.SaveAs strNewFileName 'Сохраните новый одностраничный документ
iCurrentPage = iCurrentPage + 1 'Перейти на следующую страницу
docSingle.Close 'Закройте новый документ
rngPage.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'Перейти на следующую страницу
Loop 'Перейти к началу цикла do
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Восстановление обновления экрана
'Уничтожьте объекты.
Set docMultiple = Nothing
Set docSingle = Nothing
Set rngPage = Nothing
End Sub
```

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *необходимая строка выглядит вот так: Госпошлина за рассмотрение дела в суде в отношении Иванова Ивана Ивановича (кредитный договор S_LN_2300_54352), (ИД 654234), НДС нет.* А сказать что из неё надо получить? *не могу понять почему буква Б так странно отображается (не полностью) под строкой г.. Уфа* перекрыта символом предыдущей строки. Увеличьте межстрочный интервал.

Comment: Сказано ведь, что получить нужно. Необходимы цифры около(которые в скобочках с ним) "ИД", цифры должны быть названием файла. Межстрочный интервал на каждом компьютере нужно будет изменить руками или прописать можно?

Comment: *Межстрочный интервал на каждом компьютере нужно будет изменить руками или прописать можно?* Междустрочный интервал задаётся в макете отчёта. Но необходимо следить, чтобы использованный шрифт присутствовал на целевом компьютере (посему лучше использовать стандартные для ОС шрифты).

Comment: *Необходимы цифры около(которые в скобочках с ним) "ИД",* оно всегда именно так - открывающая скобка, затем ИД (без пробела), затем пробел, затем группа цифр, затем закрывающая скобка? гарантируете?

Comment: Да, абсолютно всегда, вот так всегда и выглядит `Госпошлина за рассмотрение дела в суде в отношении Ивана Ивана Ивана (кредитный договор S_LN_5000_539105), (ИД 87276320), НДС нет.` Проблема с буквой "Б" в том, что межстрочный интервал всегда является 1.0, если больше, то весь остальной текст страдает. Причём я приложил скрина уже сделанного моим кодом файлик. В оригинале всё отлично отображается и интервал там тоже 1.0.

Comment: *Проблема с буквой "Б" в том* Это же поле? ну уменьшите чутка его высоту, чтобы не налезало... или попробуйте фон сделать прозрачным (отсутствующим).

Comment: Понял, может, в коде из-за чего-то это происходит. Пока что в приоритете название файлу нужное присвоить.

Comment: Ну код функции, который вынимает цифры из переданной строки, если их не более 15 штук, я дал. Используй.

Comment: Про функцию-то я понял, но немного непонятно как правильно изменить мой код, чтобы правильно работал с функцией. Новичок в этом деле, не совсем понимаю.

Comment: Там, где нужно имя файла, использовать функцию с параметром-исходной строкой. Но вообще - совместная отладка тут неформат, так что завязываем, пока по шее не дали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function Extract_Filename(argument As String) As String
tmp = InStr(1, argument, "(ИД ", vbBinaryCompare)
If tmp = 0 Then Exit Function
Extract_Filename = CStr(Val(Mid(argument, tmp + 4)))
End Function
```